# Parsing XML from Custom List Library to Document Library using SharePoint Designer

Tags: xml, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, document-management

So the requirement is to scan a document and upload it on SharePoint Online which will serve as their document repository.

The output of the scanned document using OCR is in XML format and will be stored in a Custom List Library using the respective fields below:

Title (Single line of text) = Contains the Title of the scanned document
XML (Multi-line of text) = Contains the indexed information from the scanned document in XML format.
Attachment = Contains the digital copy of the scanned document.

After the document has been saved in the Custom List Library the next step is to run a workflow and parse the xml data and create a new record on SharePoint Document Library containing the digital copy of the document and the parsed xml data which will be split into separate columns.

So the question is how can I parse xml data from SharePoint Custom List using SharePoint Designer and store that information to Document Library.

Does anyone of you guys have tried this before or if you have suggestion that would be great.

Thank you,

Regards
Arvin

Answer (score 0):

this is probably coming in too late but you can use a document library instead of a custom list.

Simply define a content type based on the xml schema and promote elements in the xml into columns which you can then use later.

See here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/aa543819(v%3Doffice.14)